# iOS How to check if three sprites make contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

I know how two check if two sprites make contact in spritekit (using contact.bodyA and contact.bodyB). Can someone explain how i can check if three sprite make contact with each other? (Three square sprites that make contact because they are stacked on top of each other for example)

Thx

**Edit:**
I've figured out that it's possible to use allContactedBodies, to find all contacts to one body. See code below. But the for loop gets an error, for some reason. Error:  **'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'** Does anyone how to fix this?

```
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {
    var node1:SKNode = contact.bodyA.node!
    var node2:SKNode = contact.bodyB.node!
    if ( node1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == node2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask ) {
        let bodies = node1.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()
        if bodies?.count > 3 {
            NSLog("%i", bodies!.count)
            for potentialBody : AnyObject in bodies {
                if let body = potentialBody as? SKPhysicsBody {
                    body.node?.removeFromParent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want mutual contact, such that each of the sprites is touching both of the other sprites (e.g. overlapping corners in a triangle), or just a joined touch a->b->c so that a&c aren't directly touching, but are joined via b.

Comment: If you can explain both, it would be great! Think of three balls sprites that use physics, if they make contact which each other they can be removed. So sometimes they are stacked a->c and b on top and the other times they joined touch a->b->c

Comment: the mutual overlap is easy `if (a contacts b) and (a contacts c)`. the chained overlap you'll have to test a few more variations. a->b and b->c, and b->c and a->c

Comment: Ok I understand that, thx. But in spritekit you use categoryBitMask, so in my ball example they have all the same category. And you can only check contact.bodyA and contact.bodyB at one time, there is no contact.bodyC. This part i don't understand.

Comment: But the code is almost the solution to the problem, i think!

Comment: Why are you casting to an optional in your for loop? The Apple documentation states that `allContactedBodies()` returns
"An array of SKPhysicsBody objects that this body is in contact with.", so you just need to cast each member of the resulting array to `SKPhysicsBody`. You don't need the optional either because the loop won't iterate over `nil` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this untested code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodies = contact.bodyA.node!.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies()
    if bodies.count > 1 {
        NSLog("%i", bodies!.count)
        for body:SKPhysicsBody in bodies {
            body.node!.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

First off, if the bodies are in contact, their bitmasks will at least overlap, so there isn't any need to check the bitmasks (unless you want to be as specific as possible). Also, if you assume that `contact.bodyA.node` is not nil, then you can assume that it has a `physicsBody` because it is being contacted (which is only possible with a `physicsBody`).

Also, you are interested in three (or more?) bodies coming into contact, so you only need to check for more than one body coming into contact with a single body, so the check for `> 1` means "if there are more than two bodies (eg three) involved in this contact then...".

Last of all, `bodies` contains an array of `SKPhysicsBody` objects, with no `nil` values (if they are `nil`, then they are not involved in this collision), so it is safe to cast any object in `bodies` to `SKPhysicsBody`. You can assume the `physicsBody` has an owning node unless you have free bodies not attached to nodes. If you want to be safe, just check for `nil` here.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, will try it this evening and will let you know, thx!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong format in the comment (for some reason safari don't let me edit the comment). I think the code is almost working. The contacted bodies are removed, but this won't work if you have two categories. So for example if you have balls and squares. You then get body.node??.removeFromParent in the for loop. But then all contacts will remove balls and squares. I don't know how to check in the body.node?? against the ballCategory and squareCategory? Can you help me with that.

Comment: Add that code as an update in your question and it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

squareThe following code will work, thanks for all the help:

```
func didBeginContact(contact:SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodies = contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()
    if ( bodies!.count > 1 ) {
        NSLog("%i", bodies!.count)
        for body:AnyObject in bodies ?? [] {
            if body.categoryBitMask == squareCategory {
                body.node??.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks messy to me. Why use a nil coalescing (??) operator to revert to an empty array? The empty array will never be reached as `bodies` is either empty or not. Also your code would be significantly more readable if you explicitly unwrapped some of the optionals. Adding `?` into lines like `contact.bodyA.node?.physicsBody?.allContactedBodies()` gives the impression that you think it may fail, when from what I can see it won't (didBeginContact() will ALWAYS have contacts for bodyA, so `nil` wouldn't be possible).

Comment: One more thing, instead of hardcoding `squareCategory`, just check `if body.categoryBitMask == bodyA.node!.categoryBitMask`, because if you ever change the bitmask of any node, you don't want this function to break.

Comment: Thx, i hear what you are saying. Will try to clean up the code. as you can see, i am still trying to understand swift. Will post the results, any comments later on will be most helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

This is better version:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let bodies = contact.bodyA.node!.physicsBody!.allContactedBodies()
    if (bodies.count > 1) {
        for body in bodies {
            if body.categoryBitMask == contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask {
                body.node!?.removeFromParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```